# Constructor design pattern for an entity with boolean attributes

Tags: design-patterns, builder

So I have an entity whose properties are a lot of boolean values. At first glance I thought maybe implementing a `Builder` but since probably all options are going to be `true/false` I'm not sure at all. Is there any better design pattern specifically for this all boolean properties and if possible a quick example maybe? Thanks in advance

Comment: Entities are typically mutable. What's the problem with getters and setters?

Comment: I see. The issue i'm facing is that entities might have 20 properties, so I don't know if going for a 20-params constructor or just use setters with a blank construct or going for builder pattern. What do you think?

Comment: A 20-arg constructor would be unusable, and unreadable. I would just go with a no-arg constructor and getters/setters. If you want, you can also add "withers", which would be exactly like setters, but return the entity to be able to chain calls: `Entity e = new Entity().withFoo(true).withBar(false).withFizz(true);`

Comment: you can also use a mask, if there are no more than 32 values. Like this: Enitity e = new Entity(Entity.FOO | Entity.BAR | Entity.FIZZ), where Entity.FOO = 1; Entity.BAR = 1<<1; Etity.FIZZ = 1<<2;